# Logica de registro de usuarios

Tags: php, mysql

Soy nuevo en esto, disculpen si es una pregunta muy tonta.

Tengo tres tablas *Users*, *Pacientes* y *Medicos*.

Lo que quiero es que al registrar un Paciente o un Medico, tambien se registre su Usuario.

Paciente y Medico heredaran como FK la PK de *Users*.

Quisiera ayuda con la logica, o si existe una mejor forma de hacerlo.

Mi idea es que primero registre el Usuario, e inmediatamente hacer otra consulta que extraiga el *User* con la PK mas alta y entonces registrar el *Paciente o Medico* con ese dato como FK.

Siento que esta no es la forma correcta, por eso me gustaria que me ayudaran.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno lo que yo veo es que al registrar un paciente quieres registrar un usuario y un medico, creo que la lógica indica que lo primero que debes tener registrados en tu sistemas son los usuarios y los médicos de manera independiente, la tabla pacientes es una ***tabla ternaria*** que vincula en una nueva entidad **pacientes** la calidad de un usuario y esta nueva entidad ademas podría vincular mas de un medico, debido a que un especialista podría derivar a otro según el diagnostico.

El otro detalle que veo es que pretendes extraer la PK mas alta para asignar como FK, pero esto falla porque la PK mas alta puede cambiar en cualquier momento en un sistema multiusario, lo que debes hacer es hacer la consulta a la tabla correspondiente para asignar según su PK a la tabla pacientes.

[image: base]

Entonces hacemos la consulta en la tabla user para obtener el id el cual sera nuestro FK en la tabla pacientes.

```
SELECT idusers FROM users WHERE nombre='fulano';
```

Luego el mismo proceso para los medicos

```
SELECT idmedicos FROM medicos WHERE nombre='Gregory';
```

Y bueno ya con esos datos hacemos el INSERT en la tabla pacientes, eso dependiente del lenguaje que estés usando quedaría algo asi como:

```
INSERT INTO pacientes('users_idusers','medicos_idmedicos') VALUES (idusers,idmedicos);
```

Espero esto te sea útil, saludos.

Comment: Me gusta la idea, pero en el modelo que yo tengo, tanto Pacientes como Medicos son tipos de Usuario, por ende no estan precisamente vinculados.

Entonces:

User(ID,User,password,tipo)

Medicos->(ID, ID_User,ID_Especialidad,nombre,Cargo)

Paciente->(ID. ID_User,nombre)

El ejercicio dice basicamente que debo crear un control de roles y para cada rol una Tabla diferente que guarda sus datos, pues cada rol tiene campos especiales independiente de los demas roles.

Comment: En si, existirá una tabla extra, por ejemplo FichaMedica, que sera la tabla que vinculará a los campos Medico y Paciente, cada vez que un paciente requiera atencion medica.

Comment: Claro ficha medica también podría ser si cumple tus requerimientos. Para el tema de los roles bastaría con agregar un identificador de rol en tu tabla de usuarios y definir en tu tabla de roles el tipo de rol y su identificación.